# How to remove accents from chars

Tags: java, character-encoding

In Java I want to convert certain characters to a different format. Since I dont know exact ISO numbers and charsets I can only describe like this: "Üüöäİ" should result like below:

```
 "UuoaI" = magicOperation("Üüöäİ");
```

What character encoding I need exactly for this?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with UTF-8, which is simply a way to represent characters. What you want is to remove the *accents* from the characters.